# Application of product and sum rule

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a measure space. If the probability measure admits a density $p$ it should hold by the product and summation rules that

$\displaystyle p(a|b,c,d) = \int p(a|b,e)p(e|c,d)\mathrm{d}e$

which I am not able to proof.

I can show that

$\displaystyle p(a|b)=\int p(a|b,c)p(c|b)\mathrm{d}c$

but can not reach the result.

This formular is from Bishop's Pattern Recongnition p.31 (1.68), I just renamed and formalized the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your notations. What is $E$ here? If it is a random variable or an event what does $dE$ mean?

Comment: Normally capitals $A,B,C,D,E$ are used to denote events. Is that different here and do they denote random variables? If $P$ has a density $p$ then wrt to what measure?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made an edit. These are just variables of the density.